# C++ override pure virtual method with pure virtual method

Tags: c++, interface, coding-style, abstract-class, pure-virtual

Does it ever make sense to override a pure virtual method with another pure virtual method? Are there any functional differences or perhaps code style reasons to prefer one of the following options over the other?

```
class Interface {
 public:
  virtual int method() = 0;
};

class Abstract : public Interface {
 public:
  int method() override = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Abstract {
 public:
  int method() override { return 42; }
};
```

Versus:

```
class Interface {
 public:
  virtual int method() = 0;
};

class Abstract : public Interface {};

class Implementation : public Abstract {
 public:
  int method() override { return 42; }
};
```

Comment: It only would serve to communicate something to someone reading your code.  *"Dear person looking over my Abstract code... take note that this class does indeed have a virtual function."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Both codes produce the same effect:  class `Abstract` is abstract and you can't instantiate it.

There is however a semantic difference between the two forms:

- The first form reminds clearly that the class `Abstract` is abstract (*just in case it's name would not be self-speaking enough* ;-) ). Not only does it reminds it:  it also ensures it by making sure that method is pure virtual.
- The second form means that the class `Abstract` inherits everything exactly from `Interface`. It's abstract if and only if its base class is.

This has consequences on future evolutions of your code.  For instance, if one day you change your mind and want interface to have a default implementation for `method()` :

- In the first form `Abstract` remains abstract and will not inherit the default implementation of the method.
- The second form ensures that `Abstract` would continue to inherit and behave exactly as `Interface`.

Personally I find that the second form is more intuitive and ensures better separation of concerns.  But I can imagine that there could be some situations were the first form could really make sense.

Answer (score 10):

The pure specification on a method forces an override, but it does not prevent you from providing an implementation of the method.  The following is a rare, but sometimes useful technique.

```
class Interface
{
   virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Abstract : public Interface
{
   virtual void method() = 0;
}
inline void Abstract::method() 
{ 
    do something interesting here;
}

class Concrete : public Abstract
{
   virtual void method();
}

inline void Concrete::method()
{
    // let Abstract::method() do it's thing first
    Abstract::method();
    now do something else interesting here;
 }
```

This is sometimes useful if there are several classes derived from Abstract which need some common functionality, but also need to add class specific behavior.  [and should be forced to provide that behavior.]

Comment: Note the `inline` is just to make the code make sense if it all appeared in a header.  In practice you probably should avoid inline virtual methods!