# Implementing pure virtual function from abstract base class: does override specifier have any meaning?

Tags: c++

#### Background

I just stumbled over a use case of the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) that, as far as I can tell, seems redundant and also without any particular semantics meaning, but maybe I'm missing something, hence this question. Before proceeding, I should point out that I've tried to find an answer to it here on SO, but the nearest I got were the following threads, not really answering my query (maybe someone can point out a Q&A that actually already answers my question).

- [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained)
- [C++ override pure virtual method with pure virtual method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708210/c-override-pure-virtual-method-with-pure-virtual-method)

#### Question

Consider the following abstract class:

```
struct Abstract {
  virtual ~Abstract() {};
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

Is there any reason to use the `override` specifier when implementing `foo()` in a non-abstract class derived directly from `Abstract` (as in `DerivedB` below)? I.e., when the implementation of `foo()` is already required for the derived class to be non-abstract (and not really overriding anything)?

```
/* "common" derived class implementation, in my personal experience
   (include virtual keyword for semantics) */
struct DerivedA : public Abstract {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A foo" << std::endl; }
};

/* is there any reason for having the override specifier here? */
struct DerivedB : public Abstract {
  virtual void foo() override { std::cout << "B foo" << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: 1) It helps in figuring out which methods are derived.
2) Possibly it can help compiler with some optimisations

It is the same as in java (@override)

Comment: It is a nice catch in case you change the signature in the base but forget to update the derived.

Comment: You don't technically need `virtual` in the subclass either, yet you use it. `override` is just better in that it more clearly conveys the intent.

Comment: @KrzysztofBargieł: "help" how? The compiler surely knows that that function is an override. `override` is for the humans.

Comment: @peppe there are reasons for override being implementes. If you change the signature in the base class (on a non-pure virtual function) everythign still compiles and you don't get any errors without override.

Comment: @Hayt: what I mean is that whether a function is overriding or not is *not* determined by the presence of the `override` keyword. That's a development aid, not a help for the compiler.

Comment: It is a helper for the compiler to know whether this function is intended to override something or not and generate an error if needed.

Comment: @SebastianRedl, Hayt, ...: thanks for the contributions in the discussion above; `override` in this context clearly holds some merit w.r.t. semantics and maintanability.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of `override`, but, assuming it's something that you find useful in general, then, yes, putting `override` on a virtual function that overrides a pure virtual functions is useful. Consider this rather contrived example:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual void f();
    virtual void f(int);
};
```

Now suppose that the maintainer of `Base` (perhaps even your future self) changes `Base` to look like this:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void f(int) = 0;
};
```

Now the behavior of `Derived` has quietly changed. With `override` the compiler would report an error.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, both versions are syntactically correct and legal. The `override` specifier is mainly meant to prevent unexpected behavior. The compiler will throw an error as soon as it encounters a member function marked as `override` which is not actually overriding a virtual function. This may occur if, for some reason, you change the signature of the virtual base class function. Consider this example:

```
class Abstract {
    virtual void foo() { ...}
}; 

class Derived : public Abstract {
    void foo() override { ... }
};
```

Now, if the signature of `Abstract::foo` is changed, let's say to

```
class Abstract {
    virtual void foo(int bar) { ...}
};
```

the compiler will throw an error at `Derived::foo` as it no longer overrides a function of `Abstract` which it wouldn't without the `override` qualifier. This helps you to better maintain your code. However, in your specific case (i.e. with pure virtual declarations), an error would be thrown as well. So using `override` is mainly considered "good practice", I guess. More on that topic: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Answer (score 2):

In case of pure virtual functions and compilations not really. You will get an error anyway (except in as in the example from Pete)

But the error message may be more readable if you get an error like "*your function does not override anything*" compared to later "*cannot instantiate abstract class*"

Another advantage would be while reading the declaration you know this is a derived method from a base class.

Also it is good practice to just get used to declare all overridden methods with `override`. So why make a difference here and have inconsistent style.

As to **why** it is good to have all overriden methods be declared `override`:

imagine you have

```
class A
{
    virtual void Foo();
};

class B: public A
{
    virtual void Foo() override;
};
```

And then you change `Foo` to a `const` function in `A`. Without `override` this will compile but when you call `A->foo()` and it is a B object `B->foo()` will not be called without any indication something changed there. With `override` you get an error here.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of `override` here would be to encourage maintainability. Consider below:

```
class Foo
{
public: 
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
class Derived : public Foo
{
public:
    //....
    virtual void foo(double x) override
    {
         //This throws error
    }
};
```

As you can see above, the compiler would throw an error if you compiled the above. What would happen is the compiler would complain about the function not having the same signature. Without the `override` keyword, the outcome would have differed.