# Is Virtual destructor rule inherited or not?

Tags: c++11, virtual-destructor

I have a small question about virtual destructors. It's well known that if we have an abstract class `A` (a polymorphic class) we should declare the destructor of `A` virtual.

However, assume that we have `B`, a derived class of `A`, and `C` is a derived class of `B`. In `B`, we redefine all virtual methods of `A` to make sure that `B` is not again an abstract class.

My question is wether we should declare the destructor of `B` virtual or not for the sake of its derived class such as the class `C`.

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() = default; // Good practice: virtual here

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
    virtual ~B() = default; // Is virtual required here?

    void foo() { }
};

struct C : B {

};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate indeed, in the sense that `virtual` "sticks" to destructors just likes it does to member functions.

Comment: The question isn't an _exact_ duplicate. The question here is based on the misunderstanding that you have a choice, an assumption which isn't present in the linked question. But since any answer to that question also is an answer to this question, this question is still redundant.

Comment: @MSalters that's what I'm aiming for, yes. Someone looking for "virtual destructor" will land here and be correctly redirected.

Comment: Q&A related to the semantic choice of including `virtual` or not for `virtual` (by inheritance) methods in derived classes: [Implementing pure virtual function from abstract base class: does `override` specifier have any meaning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370403).